# What optimisation method is used in ordered logistic regression?

Tags: optimization, ordered-logit, mse, mae

I am using the *polr* function in R to create an ordered logistic model and am curious to know what its optimisation method is?

It seems to perform better than other models I have tested it against when looking at mean absolute error (MAE), but performs considerably worse when looking at MSE, so I was wondering if it optimises the model based on absolute error (as opposed to ordinary least-squares regression, for instance)?

Answer (score 0):

Semiparametric ordinal regression model use the same optimization method as used for binary logistic regression: maximum likelihood.  Instead of just having simple probability elements in the calculation of the likelihood as in the binary case (for a covariate-specific P(Y=1) = p you have probability of p if Y=1 and 1-p if Y=0) you have probabilities that Y=j for a whole series of j values.  These cell probabilities are computed by differencing the ordinal model's cumulative probabilities.